# Is the train wreck thing real or propaganda?

Tags: district-9

I can think of no plausible reason why they threw in that the Prawns would cause a train wreck "for fun." The aliens also seem to murder humans while committing theft.

It seems to me after the first few train wrecks, any sort of treatment of the Prawns, certainly relocation to a more secure spot, would be justified.

Could it be that the train wrecks and even murders were just propaganda? If not, if the Prawns (not all of them, for the scientist seems to be a reasonable guy) are really this dangerous, why would the UN or foreign countries be trying to dictate to the South Africans how the Prawns should be treated.

Again, the train wreck thing does not make much sense to me. The theft, given that the Prawns certainly live in difficult circumstances, sounds reasonable but if the aliens are intelligent, as even the workers are, why would they jeopardize their position in a strange place by wanton violence?

Comment: This question's wording feels like you expect whole groups should be either wholly good or wholly bad? It's a long time since I saw District 9, but I seem to remember it did a good job of showing the prawns as a realistic range of individuals - some good, some bad, most just wanting to live their lives - while those humans who had a hostile agenda used every bad action by any individual prawn to push for hostile treatment of them all, in a very realistic way.

Comment: The Prawns we see in the movie are, in general, animals with very little in the way of actual intelligence while still having sentience, and most importantly their ethics differs substantially to ours.  Remember, they are a servile breed of their race, and we only see a few examples of their leadership - Christopher, Paul and Christophers son, who are all in hiding.  Without effective leadership, the worker breed of the Prawn race basically devolve into an intelligent (for animals) pack animal who are capable of looking after themselves but not integrating into an external society.